# keycloak user registration settings per client

Tags: keycloak

I'm building an application which requires two types of users, one is customer with less privileges and other one is for administration. I have two different frontend applications that uses same spring boot rest api.

As far as I understand, I created two clients (customer-app and admin-app) and my frontend apps use these clients for authentication.

I want to set default role when user registration happen **per client.** You can set default group and roles under "*realm settings > user registration >
default groups & roles*" but this not enough for me. I want to say if user registered to client "customer-app" assign to customer role and if registered to client "admin-app" assign to admin role.

And finally, I can decode jwt which stores user type role (customer & admin) to determine users' permissions.

I can't find a way to do this, I may have misunderstood some keycloak concepts.

Waiting for your help...

Comment: Why not have 1 client, and assign the roles to the users instead depending on if they should or not have admin rights? "user registration happen per client" how are you implementing this?

Comment: Is it necessary to assign the role on *registration* or is it ok to assign the role when the user logs in via the specific client?